# Не могу расшифровать ключ

Tags: java, android, криптография

Вот класс шифровки и расшифровки ключа

```
public class SecurityClass {




    private static  Cipher serCretss(String mode) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidKeyException {
      SecretKeySpec sks = null;
        SecureRandom sr = SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG");
        sr.setSeed("any data used as random seed".getBytes());
        KeyGenerator kg = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
        kg.init(128, sr);
        sks = new SecretKeySpec((kg.generateKey()).getEncoded(), "AES");
        Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
        if (mode.equals("d")){
            c.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, sks);
        }else {
            c.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, sks);
        }

        return c;

    }

    public static byte[] doCript(String myText) {
        byte[] encodedBytes = null;
        try {


            encodedBytes = serCretss("e").doFinal(myText.getBytes());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Crypto", "AES encryption error");
        }

        return encodedBytes;


    }

    public static byte[] decodeCript(byte[] convertbyte) {
        byte[] decodedBytes = null;
        try {
           decodedBytes = serCretss("d").doFinal(convertbyte);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Crypto", "AES decryption error");
        }

       return  decodedBytes;
    }
}
```

так делаю шифровать

```
SecurityClass.doCript(a)
```

так делаю расшифровать

```
  SecurityClass.decodeCript(a)
```

шифрует но при расшифровке дает `null`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При шифровании и дешифровании вы используете разные ключи.

Метод `serCretss()` каждый раз заново генерирует новый ключ `KeyGenerator.init()` - который использует рандомный генератор поданный ему на вход.

Comment: Спасибо большое!Да я совсем не правильно понемал суть шифровки .Исправили благодарю.